# Conditional mapping if string not null (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I using Automapper in my project

In mapper, I map the string to `ICollection`.

Here is how I do it

```
.ForMember(x => x.PropertyImages,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.Attachments.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()));
```

But if string is empty. I got error

> object not set to an instance of an object

How I can make conditional mapping, only if string not null

Comment: Where are you getting error ?  at `aa.Attachments.Split` ?  If it is then did you try `aa.Attachments?.Split` ?

Comment: When I try to make a split. I tried ? but lambda may not contain? conditional access @ManojChoudhari

Comment: Would this work?

    .ForMember(x => x.PropertyImages,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => aa.Attachments != null ? aa.Attachments.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.None).ToList() : null));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to check string

```cs
.ForMember(x => x.PropertyImages,
      opt => opt.MapFrom(aa => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(aa.Attachments) ? aa.Attachments.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.None).ToList() : new List<string>()));
```